# React-Admin: How to make <Filter> mandatory with "alwaysOn" using "list"

Tags: react-admin

I couldn't find a way to ONLY FETCH or LIST `resources`,
 when a user fills in the `<SelectInput>` (as rendered by `<ReferenceInput>`).

**Due to a domain restriction,**
I need to ask the user to choose some Customer in order to query the Orders.
Is that possible? How can I pull it off?

> To be clear, in their [Demo project](https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/), the "Orders" can be listed using "Customer" as a `<Filter>`. (see image below)

[image]

A workaround could be also valid. Thanks.

Comment: Can you kindly mention what kind of `domain restriction` is in place?

Answer (score 0):

> Ok, this is an interesting scenario.

Let's closely look at the `resource`, and how it routes to various components.
In this case, our interest is within the `<list>` and what exactly it renders:

```js
// Set up the filter
const CustomerFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    // setup your `ReferenceInput` and `SelectInput`
  </Filter>
);

// Within your rendered component (OrderList)
<List {...props} filters={<CustomerFilter />}>
 <Datagrid>
   {console.log(props)} // Look out for the `match.params` prop
   // ...
   // Check for "customer_name" param within your props (verbose)
   {match.params.customer &&
     <TextField label="Customer" source="customer_name" /> 
   } 
 </Datagrid>
</List>
```

*Please note: don't just copy/paste this code. It's a verbose version.*
The implication is that you can render `customer name` (or whatever) within your list depending on a passed parameter.